# `fetch': key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME" (KeyError) with paperclip/aws s3/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am getting a `'fetch': key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME" (KeyError)` error in rails (4.2.3) using 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3' and "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"

I have set the Keys in my environment via terminal and running `heroku config` shows them listed.

In both my config/environments/development.rb as well as in my config production.rb I have included:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

I have also included the above code in my user.rb model, but for the sake of reference it looks like this in the model:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
    styles: { medium: "300x300#", thumb: "100x100#" },
    :convert_options => {
    :thumb => "-quality 75 -strip" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :region => ENV['AWS_REGION']
    },
    :path => ":filename.:extension",
    # :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
    :default_url => "default_img.png"

    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

I have also included the env vars in my secrets.yml:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 817c07d41b8524495628fbe91fb1f0535ade65aa96a3fee379a8d16c29cc1f7b167f537442e547422ab17ee9700028a95896eb1c0717de06dfe7895d15ddb5ce
  secret_key: sk_test_xxx
  publishable_key: pk_test_xxx
  access_key_id: xxx
  secret_access_key: xxx
  s3_bucket_name: 'bucket-name'

test:
  secret_key_base: a38e71848a4d9bc63fa8dce4522add10a4931b10e6786f0cab6a9eb1643e271b992f52fa6eff672b0d03687003099c0632477dd26b246ac4e637c52c69ec4ab0

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  secret_key: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY"] %>
  publishable_key: <%= ENV["PUBLISHABLE_KEY"] %>
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  s3_bucket_name: <%= ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]%>
```

although that may not have been required. Googling around and going through the few other posts on SO related to this error have given me little to go on - does anybody have any ideas on what the issue may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'fetch': key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME"` means that the environment variables S3_BUCKET_NAME does not have a value.

In your case you are using Heroku. Follow the instructions in the link below.

For Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars.

If you are using ENV['variables'] you need to have them set in every environment. test, production and development. If you are developing on a PC, MAC, or Linux you need to make sure the environment variables are set.

For linux: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps

For OSX:
I do it the same was as linux, I just set them in my `~/.zshrc` by adding a line like this. If you aren't using zshell then add a line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

```
export ENV_VARIABLE_NAME="value"
```

For Windows:
I don't know how, but I am sure google does.

Comment: when running heroku config I get `S3_BUCKET_NAME:  giving-tree-images` - doesn't that mean that heroku has stored that value to the variable?