# Key is there but I still get `fetch': key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME" (KeyError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I know there's a ton of these asked, but I've tried to follow each one with no luck. There must be some easy mistake that I am overlooking.

I'm trying to set up S3 and Paperclip following the [Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) and set up local testing following this [Words and Code](http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/08/04/safely-storing-your-assets-paperclip-with-aws-plus-heroku/) guide. Every time I try to generate a db migration though I get the error:

`config/environments/development.rb:62:in fetch': key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME" (KeyError)`

These are my files exactly with keys replaced:

development.rb

```
config.paperlip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credientials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')
    }
  }
```

.ENV

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME=some-bucket-name
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AAAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDD
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDDEEEEE
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
```

What am I missing?

Edit: I have tried adding the ENV values to my `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profle` as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776246/fetch-key-not-found-s3-bucket-name-keyerror-with-paperclip-aws-s3-rails), with the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`fetch': key not found: "S3\_BUCKET\_NAME" (KeyError) with paperclip/aws s3/rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776246/fetch-key-not-found-s3-bucket-name-keyerror-with-paperclip-aws-s3-rails)

Comment: I don't want to set it up with a secrets.yml file as this question does. I would like to follow the Heroku documentation and secondary guide which are linked. Also, the question owner here says they didn't set their variables locally, but I believe that mine are (but would love to be proved wrong if someone sees what I'm doing wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be pretty easy with a gem.

I added `dotenv-rails` to my gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end
```

`bundle install` and good to go.

I guess I never realized that the .env file saved in the root directory wasn't loaded automatically.