# Undefined Method "authentication" for #<Napster::Client:0x0000559185ef3cf8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not used to asking questions On stack, Apologies if the format makes it hard to respond.

Anyway, I'm trying to develop an app using Ruby on Rails with the [Napster API](https://developer.napster.com/api/v2.2#overview). I am currently stuck on setting up the [client](https://github.com/Napster/napster-ruby) object that will allow me to make meta data calls.

I am setting up the client in `config/initializers` as `napster.rb`. Here is my code

```
require 'napster'

client_hash = {
 api_key: ENV["NAPSTER_API_KEY"],
 api_secret: ENV["NAPSTER_API_SECRET"],
 username: ENV["NAPSTER_USER"],
 password: ENV["NAPSTER_PW"]
}

client = Napster::Client.new(client_hash)

client.access_token

client.authentication.access_token # => returns access_token
client.authentication.refresh_token
client.authentication.expires_in
```

Now whenever I try to run `rails c` in the console I get this error

`config/initializers/napster.rb:14:in <main>: undefined method authentication' for #<Napster::Client:0x0000559185ef3cf8>`

The `ENV` variables are stored in `config/application.yml`. I'm not sure what's going on, Here is the `#<Napster::Client:0x0000559185ef3cf8>`

```
#<Napster::Client:0x0000559185ef3cf8 
@api_key=--Omitted--, 
@api_secret=--Omitted--, 
@username=--Omitted--, @password=--Omitted--, 
@request=#<Napster::Request:0x0000559185ef3b40 @faraday=# 
<Faraday::Connection:0x0000559185ef3a28 @parallel_manager=nil, 
@headers={"Authorization"=>"Basic   
Tm1KbVpHRXlOV0l0WVRJNFppMDBPVEkwTFdJM1l
6WXRPR1ExTTJSaE16WXpORE5tOllXWmlNek5oT0RFdE
5UaG1PUzAwWlRWakxXSXpNRFF0WVRJeU56bG1abUkzTmpJMA==", "User- 
Agent"=>"Faraday v0.9.2"}, @params={}, @options=# 
<Faraday::RequestOptions (empty)>, @ssl=#<Faraday::SSLOptions 
verify=true>, @default_parallel_manager=nil, @builder=# 
<Faraday::RackBuilder:0x0000559185ef3758 @handlers= 
[Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded, Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp], @app=# 
<Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded:0x0000559185efd050 @app=# 
<Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp:0x0000559185efd0c8 @app=# 
<Proc:0x0000559185efd1b8@/home/leo/.rbenv/versions/
2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/faraday- 
0.9.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:152 (lambda)>>>>, @url_prefix=# 
<URI::HTTPS https://api.napster.com/>, @proxy=nil>>, 
@access_token=--Omitted--, 
@refresh_token=--Omitted--, 
@expires_in=86399>
```

I omitted the api and access token stuff for obvious security reasons. Any thoughtful input is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have something like dotenv-rails gem in your project? ENV variables aren't loaded automatically. I had a similar issue with them here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42980676/6769558

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone  I don't have such a gem, but I think I have it working somewhat properly. I removed the  `authentication`  method and I didn't get any errors. I can still make meta data calls to the API so I'm assuming everything's fine (for now). Thanks for the input anyway :)